# NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest time

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                data, response, error in
                var taskString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println(taskString)
                if taskString == "10004" {

                    self.loginStatus=10004
                }else if taskString == "10005" {

                    self.loginStatus=10005
                }else if taskString == "10002" {

                    self.loginStatus=10002
                }else if taskString == "10003" {

                    self.loginStatus=10003
                }else if taskString == "10001" {

                    self.loginStatus=10001
                }else{

                    self.loginStatus=10000
                }
            }
            task.resume()

            println(self.loginStatus)
```

I need to get a state through a network request
I wrote the above code

```
task.resume()

println(self.loginStatus)
```

I saw it first println？
println After that change 'loginStatus' content？

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you mean by "I saw it first println？ println After that change 'loginStatus' content?"

Answer (score 3):

`NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest` is an asynchronous process that runs in a background thread. The block inside the function is called after the asynchronous process finishes downloading the data.

The execution continues after `task.resume()` statement to `println` while the `dataTaskWithRequest` executes in the background. This is why your `println` statement is executed first. To print the value after the execution of the task, put it inside the block.

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in
    var taskString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println(taskString)
    if taskString == "10004" {
        self.loginStatus=10004
    } else if taskString == "10005" {
        self.loginStatus=10005
    } else if taskString == "10002" {
        self.loginStatus=10002
    } else if taskString == "10003" {
        self.loginStatus=10003
    } else if taskString == "10001" {
        self.loginStatus=10001
    } else {
        self.loginStatus=10000
    }

    println(self.loginStatus) // print it here
}
task.resume()
```

if `loginStatus` is always an Integer, you can use `toInt` function instead of the if statements.

Thus your code is simplified to

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in
    var taskString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println(taskString)

    if let status = taskString.toInt() {
       self.loginStatus = status
    }
    else {
        self.loginStatus = 10000
    }

    println(self.loginStatus) // print it here
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Because I do bring it up loginStatus judgment  alertView message, but alertView response will be very slow in the URLSession

Comment: it has to wait till the data finishes downloading. how else can it show the response?